# RXJS Emit first result and then wait for another observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

Currently I have two observables. One returns a list of clients and the other is fired when text changes.

I would like to emit the full result of clients and then switch over to the inner observable once the user has started filtering.

I'm also trying to achieve a debounce on the text being typed.

I've put together something that doesn't work to try and explain. As it currently is it only displays clients once I start typing text.

```js
let obs = Observable.fromPromise(this.clientService.getClients())
      .map((clients) => {
        return clients.map((c) => new Client().fromObject(c));
      });

    this.clients = obs.switchMap((values) => {
        return this.searchText.valueChanges
          .debounceTime(400)
          .distinctUntilChanged()
          .map((text) => {
            return values.filter((c) => c.isMatch(text));
          });
      });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to merge your observables together :

```js
let obs = Observable.fromPromise(this.clientService.getClients())
      .map((clients) => {
        return clients.map((c) => new Client().fromObject(c));
      }).share();

let filtered = obs.switchMap((values) => {
    return this.searchText.valueChanges
        .debounceTime(400)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .map((text) => {
        return values.filter((c) => c.isMatch(text));
        });
    });

this.clients = Observable.merge(obs,filtered);
```

first you need to use the `share` operator to avoid fetching clients twice (see edit further). then you need to get the value from `obs` and also from `filtered`. this is what `merge` is made for :

> Creates an output Observable which concurrently emits all values from every given input Observable.
>
> > *Flattens multiple Observables together by blending their values into one Observable.*
>
> [image]

[[source]](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#static-method-merge)

**Edit :** The `share` part is not necessary in this specific case as the OP is using a promise as observable source, promises not being triggered by the subscription, they are [hot observables](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/16/cold-vs-hot-observables.html) and do not need to be shared. But if you are dealing with other observable source (like angular `Http` service's method, you might need to `share`.

Comment: Wow was missing something so small! Thanks

Comment: I just checked and the promise is only created once, even without share. IE not going to server more than once.

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't think it was a `fromPromise`, promises are hot observables, so no need to share, indeed....